# My collapsed menu list is not showing outside its parent. The menu list expands the parent but not he list within each menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I have a navigation menu set up and on the desktop it works. For moblie screensthe icon expands the parent and displays all the menu items.

The challenge I have is when I click a menu item the list doesn't expand the parent box and the list is hidden within the parent.

I tried changing `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: visible` but that just expands the menu from the outset.

I've tried setting `z-index` but that doesn't appear to work either.

Most of the CSS is just copied from bootstrap

Just a noob so may need to provide more css.

```css
.navbar .btn-navbar {
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs::after,
.nav-pills::after {
  clear: both;
}

nav .nav li {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation">
  <div id="navigation">

    <div class="navbar">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-collapse">
      <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="html5" />
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="title">
      <H1>TITLE</H1>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to see the list visible over everything else when the menu name is selected. As it is I see some items but they always stop at the bottom of the parent and hide behind it.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a fixed height on your `#navigation` (could be px, em, rem,...)
For example :

```
#navigation {
    height: 52px;
}
```

You may also need to add a `background-color` on your `.nav-collapse`

**Edit :**
I added this code in the head tag which resolve some problems

```
<style>
  @media (max-width: 979px) {

    nav.navigation {
      display: grid;
      justify-items : center;
    }

    div#navigation {
      max-height : 60px;

    }
    div#navigation a.btn-navbar {
      padding: 7px 50px; }

    div#navigation .nav-collapse {
      max-height : 0;
      transition: max-height .5s;
    }

    div#navigation:hover .nav-collapse,
    .nav-collapse:hover
    {
      max-height : 130px;
    }
    div.title h1 {
      margin:0;
      padding 2px;
      text-align : center;
    }   
  }
</style>
```

But there are more, and to be honest, to me this is a Bootstrap question more than a CSS question because it's probably easy to solve with a good understanding of bootstrap functionalities. You should think about clarifying your question title on that point (for example *"Bootstrap menu always visible on mobile devices"*)

Comment: Still not working as expected. The height adjustment expands the length of this div making a large gap between this and the site content. However it does display the list items fully. If I could display those list items over the boundary of #navigation then I believe it would work. I believe I've narrowed the restriction down to this: `<div class="nav-collapse in collapse" style="height: 130px;">` as the menu list items do not expand past this boundary; however `overflow: visible` then places the menu list permanently over the next div - which is the title of the page.

Comment: Could you make a working Snipet or Pen, fiddle, site... with what you have so far please. You could also add "bootstrap menu" in your title if that is what you are using

Comment: Thanks. Learned something today :-) reduced widths reproduces the issue - https://codepen.io/JohnSmithers101/pen/VoqXYG

Comment: Did an edit, but though I am ok at CSS, i know nothing at Bootstrap which make it difficult

Comment: Thanks for the help Pierre. Unfortunately I'm still not seeing it? I reduced the width and getting the same issue :-(